# Can't see changed files within Intelij after applying TortoiseSVN patch

Tags: svn, intellij-idea, merge, tortoisesvn, patch

I have made changes to my `Java` project using a `Tortoise SVN` patch, adding a new module and altering existing files.

The patch seems to work ok, and when I look at the project I applied the patch to in the `File Explorer` I can see the new Module and Files with the Intelij "added" symbol `(+)` beside them.

However, when I open the project in `Intelij` I cannot see my new Module within the Project tab and I can only see some of the files I have merged in the `Changelist`.

What could be causing this, and how can I fix it?